# useGTF with ReactJS example works in Sandbox, but does not work locally

Tags: reactjs, canvas, sandbox, react-three-fiber

Code to load and display a GLTF format file works in sandbox. Just what I was looking for. The code [(https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-easley-lwmpi?file=/src/App.js)](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-easley-lwmpi?file=/src/App.js) not my code, but copied. Works with my own data in Sandbox. When creating a react app, with identical package levels, it always fails. Interestingly different browsers report slightly different errors.

**Sandbox & Local Code**

```
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import { Canvas } from "react-three-fiber";
import { OrbitControls, useGLTF } from "@react-three/drei";

function Model(props) {
    const { scene } = useGLTF('untitled.glb');
    return <primitive object={scene} />;
}

export default function App() {

    return (
    <Canvas pixelRatio={[1, 2]} camera={{ position: [-10, 15, 15], fov: 50 }}>
    <ambientLight intensity={1} />
    <Suspense fallback={null}>
    <Model />
    </Suspense>
    <OrbitControls />
    </Canvas>
    );
}
```

**CHROME Errors**

Uncaught R3F hooks can only be used within the Canvas component!  index.js:1 The above error occurred in the ForwardRef component:

```
at [http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:5788:5][2]
at Canvas [(http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:128676:66)][2]
```

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.

```
Visit [https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries][2] to learn more about error boundaries.
console.<computed> @ index.js:1
react-reconciler.development.js:2559
```

Uncaught R3F hooks can only be used within the Canvas component!  index.js:1 The above error occurred in the  component:

```
at Content [(http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:128849:3)][2]
at div
at ResizeContainer [(http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:128876:5)][2]
at Canvas [(http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:128937:3)][2]
at App
```

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit [https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries](http://%20https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries) to learn more about error boundaries.
console. @ index.js:1
react-dom.development.js:11340 Uncaught R3F hooks can only be used within the Canvas component!

**FIREFOX**
Uncaught R3F hooks can only be used within the Canvas component! react-three-fiber.esm.js:1340
The above error occurred in the ForwardRef component:

```
[./node_modules/@react-three/drei/core/OrbitControls.js/OrbitControls<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:5791:7][3]
Canvas@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:128676:66
```

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit [https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries](http://%20https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries) to learn more about error boundaries. index.js:1
Uncaught R3F hooks can only be used within the Canvas component! react-refresh-runtime.development.js:320
Uncaught R3F hooks can only be used within the Canvas component! react-three-fiber.esm.js:1340
The above error occurred in the ForwardRef component:

```
[./node_modules/@react-three/drei/core/OrbitControls.js/OrbitControls<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:5791:7
Canvas@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:128676:66][3]
```

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries. index.js:1
Uncaught R3F hooks can only be used within the Canvas component!  react-reconciler.development.js:2561
The above error occurred in the  component:

Content@[http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:128848:17](http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors%7Emain.chunk.js:128848:17)

```
div
```

ResizeContainer@[http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:128898:7](http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors%7Emain.chunk.js:128898:7)
Canvas@[http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:128936:94](http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors%7Emain.chunk.js:128936:94)

```
App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit [https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries][3] to learn more about error boundaries. index.js:1
Uncaught R3F hooks can only be used within the Canvas component! react-dom.development.js:11342
```

**MS EDGE**

```
Fetch finished loading: GET "<URL>".
Fetch finished loading: GET ["http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js".][7]
Fetch finished loading: GET ["http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js".][7]
Fetch finished loading: GET ["http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js.map".][7]
Fetch finished loading: GET ["http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js.map".][7]
Fetch finished loading: GET "http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js.map".[enter link description here][7]

XHR finished loading: GET ["http://localhost:3000/untitled.glb".][7]
Fetch finished loading: GET "blob:[http://localhost:3000/9be11f26-da7b-40c2-bf56-039313b88773".][7]
Fetch finished loading: GET "blob:[http://localhost:3000/5fe62429-1fd1-4b68-88b0-1ae7695a70ea".][7]
Fetch finished loading: GET "blob:[http://localhost:3000/bfaaf41b-7dc8-45e0-bbb8-9603ffa30111".][7]
Fetch finished loading: GET "blob:[http://localhost:3000/7a0884c3-5fcc-4fb3-9c7e-b3f7ab547c4f".][7]
```

Comment: Try downloading the code straight from codesandbox using the 'Export to ZIP' button. Execute it using `npm start`. Theres should be no difference

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have an issue with version, useGLTF is not detecting and older verson of canvas. The package is now called @react-three/fiber, it is the package that works with three ecosystem packages which are named in the similar format, as here in your code @react-three/drei

Update to the newest versions or check out the version on this template that i have compiled https://github.com/Epiczzor/r3f-template

Also, You need to use GLTFJSX to auto generate a react component for your GLTF/GLB